# What Are App ID and Role APN in the Amazon AWS S3 JavaScript SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-javascript-sdk

I am looking over the sample code at http://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/browser/ for using CORS to upload files onto S3.

In the JS example code, there are references to `YOUR_APP_ID` and `YOUR_ROLE_ARN`. What are those values and where do I find them in my AWS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`YOUR_APP_ID` --> The Facebook app Id [[Facebook Developers]](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/)

`YOUR_ROLE_ARN` --> ARN of your IAM Role [AWS IAM](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/) Location : `IAM > Role > <role_name>`